# When were KYC questions introduced in the EU?

Tags: european-union, regulation, money-laundering, history, know-your-customer

The Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know_your_customer) on KYC doesn't provide that information. I believe it happened a few years after 9/11 so it is hard to google — all results I get are much more recent.

Specifically, I am interested in when banks in the EU started to ask questions about what the source of your income is, if you or your relatives are [politically exposed persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politically_exposed_person) (PEP), etc.

Comment: PEP feels _very_ recent. KYC I remember being a thing in the early 2000s.

Comment: Searching for `site:fatf-gafi.org KYC`, after a few minutes, the oldest document I found was from [June 2003](https://www.fatf-gafi.org/media/fatf/BPP%20SRVI%20June%202003%202012.pdf) [PDF], on fighting Hawala and the like.